# sddm-Greeter crashes on startup Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: ati, kubuntu, 15.04

Yesterday I updated from Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.04... Update went fine, the system booted and allowed me to mess with themes and to install the proprietary ATI drivers... I then rebooted the system and I was welcomed by a sddm-greeter crash which wouldn't allow me to get to the login page... I'm sure restoring the default graphics drivers would fix the issue but, through the terminal, I have no idea how to do so... 
Any idea on how to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that I have a similar Problem but in my case sddm-greeter is crashing after login.
I'm running an Nvidia card with the official drivers so I'm not sure if restoring the default grafics driver would fix your problem.
Do you have access to a command line? If you have uninstalling the ATI drivers with `apt-get remove` should be the way. If this is no solution for you think about installing another Display Manager (like KDM) to get into the DE. That is not the best Solution but it should work until someone found a fix.
I'm not really into Ubuntu but I think 15.04 is using systemd. In this case disable sddm by using `# systemctl disable sddm` and enable another by `# systemctl enable kdm` (in case of KDM).